# Usage of the word "sensual" with music

Tags: adjectives

Is it right to say **sensual music**? What is its meaning when used like this?

Comment: "Writing about music is like dancing about architecture"

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of *sensual* is "of or arousing gratification of the senses and physical, especially sexual, pleasure." In  the sense of "arousing gratifications of the senses," the word could be used when referring to music.

The NOAD has the following note, about the usage of *sensual*:

> The words *sensual* and *sensuous* are frequently used interchangeably to mean "gratifying the senses," especially in a sexual sense. Strictly speaking, this goes against a traditional distinction, by which *sensuous* is a more neutral term, meaning "relating to the senses rather than the intellect" (*swimming is a beautiful, sensuous experience*), while *sensual* relates to gratification of the senses, especially sexually (*a sensual massage*). In fact, the word *sensuous* is thought to have been invented by John Milton (1641) in a deliberate attempt to avoid the sexual overtones of *sensual*. In practice, the connotations are such that it is difficult to use *sensuous* in Milton's sense. While traditionalists struggle to maintain a distinction, the evidence suggests that the neutral use of *sensuous* is rare in modern English. If a neutral use is intended, it is advisable to use alternative wording.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Yeats used it to great effect in his poem "Sailing to Byzantium":

```
Caught in that sensual music all neglect
Monuments of unageing intellect.
```

(N.B. This is also the poem that gave the Coen brothers'*  *No country for old men*)

*Sensual* is an adjective meaning physical, carnal, bodily, etc. It is often confused or conflated with *sensuous*, which means sexy, attractive, luxurious, etc.

* *Via Cormac McCarthy (thanks for the reminder, @Callithumpian).*

Comment: Gave Cormac McCarthy "No country for old men."

Comment: @Callithumpian: Good point.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the reference. I didn't know it was a borrowed phrase.